# core gore graphics and alpha values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am draw some circle on a map with

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect
```

This works great, but the only issue is that I have the alpha value set to .5
If tow or more circle overlap the the overlap area is darker because of the two alpha values being added I suppose.  Is there an easy way to maintain the same alpha value regardless if the circle overlap?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with closed shapes and drawing them all in the same drawrect (or at least in the same context) you can accomplish what you want by using UIBezierPath.

```
// create a path with a circle
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(50, 50) radius:50.0f startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0f clockwise:YES];

// add another circle to the path
[path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:50.0f startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0f clockwise:YES]];

// draw them both, since they are in a single path they will be treated as a single shape
[path fill];
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw the circles at full opacity, and set the opacity of the view/layer to `0.5`.

EDIT:

To clarify, I assume you know how to stop drawing your circles at half opacity, since you managed to set it up that way in the first place. So make the opacity of your circles be `1.0`. Then, set your view's opacity to `0.5` by doing the following:

```
view.alpha = 0.5;
```

I'm assuming you have a `UIView` subclass, so this can either be in the place in your code where you create the view or it could be inside the subclass in your init method for it. So if you're doing it from within the `UIView` subclass, it would be `self` instead of `view`:

```
self.alpha = 0.5;
```

Also, this will make all of the drawing you do in this view be `0.5` opacity. If you want to have some content that's full opacity and some that's half opacity, the simplest solution I can give you is to have two different views, one for the half opacity content, the other for the full opacity content. There are better ways to accomplish this, but for the sake of communicating easily a solution, this is probably easiest.

Comment: Could you provide a simple code sample? I'm somewhat new at the core graphics and layer piece.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I might add, that I have other points being drawn that do not have any opacity set. It is just for the circles

Comment: @jdross, are you drawing in a `UIView` by overriding the `drawRect:` method, or are you drawing to a `CALayer?` I can give you a better code example if you clarify. Also, this would make the opacity be `0.5` for all of the content that you're drawing. If you want to accomplish this with only some of your content, it is more complicated.

Comment: I am drawing in a drawrect: